# Special Sequences , that will take text as input and output all of the hashtags in it separately

Tags: python

```
import re
text = input()
match = re.findall(r"\w+",text)
if match:
 print("\n".join(match))
```

Why didn't my code work?
Where is my fault?

Sample Input:

```
No #pressure, no #diamonds
```

Sample Output:

```
#pressure
#diamonds
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not include a hashtag. Use `#\w+` to make sure matches start with `#`.

```py
import re

text = input()
match = re.findall(r"#\w+", text)

if match:
    print("\n".join(match))
```

Example:

> ```
> >>> import re
> >>> text = input()
> #pressure, no #diamonds
> >>> match = re.findall(r"#\w+", text)
> >>> if match:
> ...     print("\n".join(match))
> ... 
> #pressure
> #diamonds
> ```

You could also reduce this to:

```
import re

text = input('Enter text:\n> ')
print(' '.join(re.findall(r"#\w+", text)))

# Enter input:
# > #pressure, no #diamonds
# #pressure #diamonds
```

Comment: @ErfanShokrollahzade No problem, I recommend you check out [RegexOne](https://regexone.com/) and use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to prototype and debug your regex. Both great tools.